# Simple Interest Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I have some trouble finding sense from the simple interest formula and compound interest formula.

I have look everywhere online, and they all agree that the simple interest formula is $I = prt$.
Similarly, I see that the compound interest formula is $I = P(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$

Logically, the compound interest should work for a simple interest problem too.

Therefore, if we arbitrarily use a principal of 100, and a rate of 10% growth for two years, we will get the following formulas:
$I = 100(1.1)(2) = 100(1.1)(2)$
$I = (100)(1.1)^{(1)(2)} = 100(1.1)^2$

Clearly, the two formulas are different. I have come up with my own conclusion that the simple interest formula on the web is wrong, and it should be $i = pr^t$. Can anyone confirm/debunk this. Please tell me why I am wrong/right. Much appreciated

Comment: Simple interest should be $P(1+rt)$.

Comment: With the formula  $P(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$ you can calculate the capital which you get after $nt$ periods if  the initial capital $P$ is compounded $n$ times during the year. For instance you have $P=\$200$ and and an interest rate of $r=12\%$. The capital is compunded every three months. Then after $t=2$ years  you will have a capital of $\$200\cdot (1+\frac {0.12}4)^{4\cdot 2}=\$200\cdot 1.03^8=\$253.35$

Answer (score 1):

The difference between simple and compound interest is that for simple interest you only get interest on the original principal, not on the accumulated interest.

If you deposit $100$ for two years at $10\%$ per year, simple interest pays you $10$ each year and you wind up with $120$. The interest is $prt=100 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 2=20$

Compound interest will pay you $10$ at the end of the first year, giving a balance of $110$. The second year it will pay interest on the your new balance of $100$, netting you $11$ for a balance of $121$ at the end of the second year. Now the final value (which your formula has as I but should be $I+P$) is $100(1+0.1)^2=121$.